# How to filter array if filter is in angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to create general directive for filtering array in angular.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    controller: <input type="text" ng-model="query.name" /> - work<br>
    directive: <span filter by="name"></span> - not work
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:query">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

controller and directive are:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = [
        {id: 1, name:'aaa'},
        {id: 2, name:'bbb'},
        {id: 3, name:'ccc'}
    ];
});

app.directive('filter', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            by: '@'
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.append(
                '<input type="text" ng-model="query.' + attrs.by + '">');
        }
    }
});
```

Filter in controller works but filter in directive doesn't. I don't know how to fix it.

Solution is fixed in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WLGd6RPQEwMFRBvWslpt?p=preview

Comment: This is a very odd approach to filtering.  Even if you could dynamically add elements like you're doing via `link`, `query.name` will never resolve inside your directive because you've isolated your scope (you'd have to use `$parent.query.name`, which isn't a good idea).

Comment: Yes this looks odd, because I simplified it more than was necessary. I used link because sometimes I need create `<input type="text"` another time `<select><option>....` depend on list columns config.

I tried to create general (universal) filter which doesn't know about data and create filter depend on meta data from config array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have isolated the scopes you have to use eiter $parent or you have to set up two way binding using '=' i have update your example with two way binding

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  controller: <input type="text" ng-model="query.name" /> - work<br>
  directive: <span filter by="query"></span> - not work
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:query">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.list = [
              { id: 1, name: 'aaa' },
              { id: 2, name: 'bbb' },
              { id: 3, name: 'ccc' }
            ];
            alert("123");
            $scope.query = { name: "" }
        });

        app.directive('filter', function () {
            return {
                scope: {
                    by: '='
                },
                replace: true,
                template:'<input ng-model="by.name"></input>'

            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but you used `name` inside in directive. But I need to create general directive, which doesn't know about columns of data. So my primary problem is how to pass column name in variable. Now it is `name` but for other dataset will be anything else

Comment: @MarekL then you just need to specify `by="query.name"` and change your directive to say `ng-model="by"`: http://jsfiddle.net/SCvJn/